how to display html component on executed stories angular
enter image description here
enter image description here
Good evening to you, I hope you are well, I have a small problem currently that I am working in the stories file of my component. I have two methods, the first method displays a data table but the second is a set object. but if I reverse the display order, it is now the first method which will return a set object and the second method will be correct. and finally I would like to know how to display its html component in the executed stories. thank you for your help 
